# Require prints a symbol

Tags: php, json, include

When i require a php file, it prints a symbol.

Code:

```
    echo 'test'; 
    include('1.php');
    echo 'test';
```

Result in browser:

```
testtest
```

BUT! When I tried to parse a page with Jquery Json parser, It returned an error, because it said that there is a symbol right in the place where require function was called. You can't see this symbol in browser, but online Json parser can.

Copy and paste the result from browser to online Json parser:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fh7f.png)

So the question is how do I fix this error?
And yes, there are 100% no empty spaces anywhere in included code or somewhere else.

Comment: Show content of 1.php. And by the way in a good browser you can see sourcecode. Right-Click show source.

Comment: It's a UTF8 BOM, try saving 1.php as utf-8 without BOM

Comment: Remove last closing `?>` in 1.php

Comment: 1.php is just <? ?>

Answer (score 2):

There is a chance of the required file to have a UTF8 encoding with BOM characters. If that's the case you could try converting your file (1.php) to UTF8 without BOM.

More about BOM [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/5451383)